# Nested bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks

Can we have nested bookmarks, working like a filesystem:

```
% Bookmark
- --------
  dir-1                         
  dir-2                         
  ...
  mark-n                         ~/work/file-n.txt
```

When I open dir-1 I have another screen with bookmarks, located in this dir:

```
% Bookmark
- --------
  dir-1-1                         ~/work/file-1.txt
  dir-1-2                         ~/work/file-2.txt
  mark-1                         ~/work/file-n.txt
```

So, we upgrade the bookmarks data structure from a list to a tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus).

You would do it slightly differently from what you describe. You can *bookmark* (1) a [bookmark-list display](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#bookmark-listBookmarks) or (2) a [bookmark file](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkFileBookmarks).  When you "jump" to such a bookmark you (1) get that display or (2) switch to using that bookmark file.

(You can also bookmark an Emacs desktop -- when you "jump" to such a bookmark you switch to that desktop.)